# Python not counting the right answer

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to count the number of 8's from a text file, but it didn't show the correct answer. It's supposed to be 50 8's, but my code only counts 40.

```
from sys import argv

counter = 0

if len(argv) == 1:
    print("ERROR! You forgot to type something")
else:
    for a in open(argv[1]):
        if a.count("8"):
            counter += 1
    print(counter)
```

Right below is the text file. (Answer is 50 8's). I noticed that if there are two or more 8's in a single line, my code will only still count it as one.

```
% E / C 8 H 4 G # p A   % 7 H i G 7 O 7 X W K P : z < y D ^ z z 6 P > ^ A j % b 
3 G ` a , o ` } w k / 4 ; 4 s _ N | Z ) \ ' B \ t P $ ? % q h c + G ! t - ) n c 
6 i ; X o ; + N " * q + ? B v K D ) $ s _ P t = n 3 5 | t 7 3 U v 2 8 = ? i r R 
& F ( = [ , 6 W r 5 ` t 0 5 & E 9 ( : Q   F W ; B 0 t ; 4 X e ` " H + i ; j q 1 
9 6 R . B L H \ b Y X m [ M ` 2 = K 3 % b p c < J G 4 [ S $ % ; u t i p % v s * 
c c c t   . n S D + $ u F 9 Z G Q Z K q l K $ r W l s g m / ? 8 { I   < % > G L 
' i I " q = o W n N < > u " 9 ` 3 ^ % T q G P e E \ [ K p k V m s % m 6 @ L | m 
Z # k B = u ) 5 r y % } M P ' Q ? 5 ` g 1 @ U L o Y ! b R : k + ; } z c e * U U 
Y J i ? Q " ,   z = N 6 q } L \ . ; # 5 S N . $ T 9 r w e G X < K 4 + V V ^ { ; 
b ! $ ! 5 g S b 9 y ] O c z * # ^ ! x $ h + / 4 6 > ] } % i J F # ( b 4 E S p r 
' B o # i f ( \ A * i r 5 +   8 b % [ F % ) D u ) 7 z n ] Q a L S j x } u n ; L 
q = @ N q l 8 0 A   k g - ^ ] 6 l ? R v Y ] ( ( B ] ] U z ( ! 5 ^ ] c @ 8 8 a ? 
T I F O l v = M k & G f T a 6 = 6 q p O a { : < : ^ " Q _ : j B M ` . : { # L } 
h h D A K C % 8 { 8 5 " 7 : F L k d ) f u c F | 5 k C 9 ' I * > f ] @ } ; # K k 
@ _ T q J f v 6 O A 7 G U ] G I i , } # ; C ] | d " 4 % u C   V g , ' q M d 7 2 
+ Q h I B m k C 5 8 n u 3 | S _ 2 & _ k : o ) V X a > M C \ s ( < y W ) i { g 9 
` s d t e . T 0 ) R > U C t X ] K G ( { k T E o Z M V _ h D > + Y   q 1 R | % f 
[ * h r 1 ( $ U # t q S f J a ? p ? ) 3 p C t s g z # ! I & % < K V 7 y T { 3 t 
q & F " O j @ + h N / m 5 { A . L | % B ] < 8 w t Y z . 1 f : R i L j Z J Z & u 
1 | h D ; P ( M j N + p l Q c 8 = X % h = t H + 5 g T / 6 y 2 { U 7 z c , N S   
` o C K m h d 6 [ n E k \ E   r . m D G d q P 9 r K ' u N 5 i g 6 w = U [ 9 . ] 
' q k * y } { O z z n v @ d o ^ x t S J _ w I 4 u - J ` _ % " ) t 4 2 M x ' - R 
u l Z n 1 , . ] ( 6 ! E u H n R h 8 r X B C _ d H 5 4 & d V Z \ W < x A P $ G < 
= { ( 7 ^ F A & l ` z 1 0 ` { @ ) > c n X G y E r : C 1 & [ n _ a a 2 z J ; # R 
2 V % R i G 5 H i 9 c : N - V # w 6 m L ` ; ! J E P 4 ^ T P K O Z > > { l D . D 
* % 6 5 X x { c b e { m h = F ( l B 7 M 3 ] j N U x J / b y M h ( Y [ q h s " ^ 
N q p q , p ^ & C L ! $ f i 0 C j k ] 3 & b _ f b - f j # ` 3 t z F v m X I A n 
O S Q 0 : a 0 M R ? O p 0 . 8 L p K [ N w I t r 3 ' 2 \ x o P ` 1 A = 2 . M f q 
( z | Z % d 7 j 2 j $ Z w ' S U F H w * h N X C b y z F $ o * J ! % E , _ m 2 j 
H T O l ` j z V @ t F U U . ; j ' / 4 < x f 0 3 h 1 Z 7 V 6 C b B d . < C " J f 
X E / \ b < Z 2 O q ; i P y u - } 8 % P k U U ] R - + $ n V ) Y _ . B M e ] # V 
U M v 0 Y g 8 X + & z D 5 ! x d U @ l _ p 6 q L ^ % b $ P G f \ S < H E ! _ | ' 
c b P ^ $ 4 R { $ C X t 4 Q q @ x 8 @ y [ f ! l D v b ] < ?   M / ? < n q D w \ 
1 0 H k r t F K B < D = g j f w j Y * K ) 2 l x ! r J [ o R J ? | q r Z z 0 : \ 
Q H I / 5 * { } y f 8 8 = c 4 x b $ - B C $ O O 5 [ * 8 n G i 4 I L d r N X ` M 
J 3 o * g ) 7 , z : } U y 3 T j p S ? J } t v w D { 2 * y d T n o k 3 2 s Y D F 
S ! U G Q 0 2 ] ; y % X ' \ K 6 + i 5 r O F } J 7 [ $ F j Q x [ b x p K | z o { 
, h q 4 a & - ^ 7 y H } U ) & s f Y p R < N i ^ { N y ( 5 c P t ` F * , = , [ T 
{ ) p c l T k P m i L e M [ + # \ < V = 9 ' 8 P # W   2 { W d s   " I o < k @ K 
L n = V * ( l z T & u @ | w ] # m h \ s / j ? N u v l m J i O y M K o < S 4 T u 
c 3 , I t % ! X W G L 8 G V Y 4 K Y ? L 9 3 & q > s _ ] b 7 ^ T & v K O U ; R Y 
t ! ] v ' b v ` V Y P _ O * Z s 1 0 l } : ] k A , 4 d & % U ; m s l r 8 m C | s 
4 0 ^ Y & Q , c ` m \ z + u / C l / P w { L ( n h < ( g D ; e A o y t ' > { s u 
b ( % D z # b q - 2 s 2 X ] - A Y U _ X w j S 4 q v @ < _ # E e r R 8 l ( J o | 
& X T " [ e e s , 0 M 3 a V   m \ k p g $ \ R k / D f - T \ , A 4 ( h ` u . W 7 
k & E 2 @ N ) 5 J ] d Y Y Y ] V 3 ) | & : 1 E g n X S I p J 4 B u   f : M p # 8 
$ , $ & E j x ] ^ d 2 N Z R x U H ! a Y t I % % w s . R q p @ N , o ! I : L j # 
@ K w j v 0 1 E q < - S R x T ! t f @ R v R _ c P ; s $ _ H F ( @ $ d ( L Q 8 S 
! O # m F >   d * W > & q o t B ) $ s j ` 2 = N v > K 6 P 7 2 U s % / 0 ( V C d 
a q T O % 3 u G R I i c   " 8 s P Y t $ W < y V = * 4 n g ; o ` ` n Q o ) 9 [ < 
k N C ( 4 | { S ? ; u   y > ( s * ( 7 Q ^ % D k o S 0 L ( $ q 4 C B _ W p q 4 b 
1 4 q < = r > 1 o 5 & r R s # 1 } c q F [ ; 5 O @ } } u q . k y q 9 ` K e x X , 
{ I k L X | 0 C 4 2 6 L ! B z E . E e N n f u 2 f j ( + e 7 1 O ` ( C < d N Q x 
C A G p + + v p 3   + j X t : k   , N M X   / ` * + 2 y * c 3 3 _ ) 7 U O N = c 
/ c K R ] i h 8 y * 0 x u ; # m , ) c ( " 4 D } K d t < 7   \ " , " Y P y = j z 
% W w A 6 t d 5 ^ W 5 e 5 G * Z ! H G ; z u I Z H l m J G Y ' Y * r * K 2 w V L 
Q G P j B ) a j a d ` I N H 5 r B 5 d E z ] A a { B 3 { E c t d b C h E " C 4 i 
$ H ? K u P 1 j P 7 p * - b > U V x [ r ! V H o B d @ S l U a U . U # G ' \ % * 
$ = 3 " = m T [ J W 6 9 - o ? W % ( g N & V ; / % r i , V < q u S [ B 9 N ( f * 
L p v P c h . d g ; R J X , 1 y N ; S " 4 B i , t X ^ , _ , j w 7 J w v D b ; 0 
4 P A ' ' S U 8 K n p r k 2 f ] X p y ^ n / 6 0 Z ^ I \ h ) J y z < y 1 J ? / n 
= _ q } Y d F 5 3 J 8 f D @ ^ _ m % ] 9 e o T H ^ ' E D w C " Z ] R 9 : & , `   
1 \ 8 6 H m ? 1 i q 2 N . D ` , 9 C ( l / w e K [ 8 b ` - U Z w w o Q Z > t g X 
* ] * P O 2 O v > U ) n n ) v % 3 ` " ^ v J # b ) 2 O c $ v [ r + g ' W % $ Z j 
/ F A t K ? 6 m a e $ v u o < ^ 2 8 N s " G V y ^ { < 0 { Y P { = } } 6 g 5 R ) 
: o 2 . S H u * L < 0 @ [ m > > w x S > j m D _ ^ W _ o ! B [ 4 z N W - E G > _ 
| j - w + N c b   t q c } _ S . z l ( 5 / U 2 l 7 2 $ n Z 5 N ) ' L ) z A ? % 8 
T % R j x _ e B { e < M l * 2 . H N O e ! } ] ( } R z W u _ C { - A W W h f ! } 
# @ C % y > T _ W L E ? I t l I r O \ 7 v l } W ^ o Z i j u R % < p p x b 2 A I 
, < F g i @ W D u 0 n T > d " _ M L 2 < o 5 u s 8 L L O ] C - v ) 2 3 S 8 m Z 5 
q 3 : < { T / 6 ` I I 0 # ] L _ % w ` c 9 0 s V y M U a ? m C ! i r 4   | / D L 
v } B z N ) - B # R U * s u & w 6 * H [ u 7 U b ) C 9 C { K ! , P n = I Y K + 1 
- { E ! m : : = Y / D ] . $ x 9 h C K P \ y Y w * r % s / f 3 L J T [ ] " / ' % 
j v ) 6 [ 1 ^ 8 ! % d w - q ; U P a 2 O x : & 0 [ @ _ D l > B R x q , e $ u ! H 
| E N 7 l W k w . 8 # V ? { | S Q Z q s 4 V p Q m 6 a $ 6 K t ` } " o u e c ( c 
a F o f @ W R ` [ ; C O B v 8 E L W s \ r l C 0 h 5 ^ ? \ > \ A @ U Z w U 9 s , 
d Y A K P % M d e j e Q D + 4 b 0 S E 9 V w 3 F 2 9 0 E ^ m | = D k o = ' u M ] 
. / k W Q ) I 5 & W q P $ ] F $ > t h Y e F 5 0 ` ' % 2 A T 8 ` j v Y s 7 " b e 
O A Q k j $ a 6 | , } # 4 ! 3 N _ U H B 0 ( B 9 G m T A 0 m ! 3 , j y ) + + . u 
G d ? l \ 3 n O 2 N z P : w _ h \ 4 b B B _ z u " t b ( o ( c k r $ p G { f Q + 
E E C D d * ] ; F & ' f e c G l M # A % g : 1 C 3 g Z - h R r Q P Z S 0 o z f f 
@ U f c c = l ? M m ! q j e [ ; ^ E 6 U w < : @ M b m . > d L z V b P 0 Y E e 1 
$ , x L T   d ' @ ) - o > ^ $ / h 3 M 5 o b M w G > C | * > 6 Y + g ] M i ] > 9 
_ + { $ o $ T _ } = 0 W n 4 F & G 5 M S \ r C W X 6 . 2 w w z g b [ a 4 S i p ( 
j w R : g ( ^ c ? g ! J h h Q X b 6 ^ g o / h a G 5 q T ( / 4 ; N S \ $ R & z T 
O D N B E 8 r 7 O ) F f P ; . K b a Y = 8 e ; . % W k u K ] s > ) j { y 1 < e I 
s " | w r - t : U X _ e r M ) ] b Q % ! B w + E h ! c . X g { Q V A c I k q - v 
p | = o ] 1 _ * z N + E . c j f 2 z i @ 8 5 ? m a R ] " x ( ] | 3   1 3 Y e Q : 
> ` { p V n @ ` " , z " t s r < < . S p ! 8 $ 9 [ ^ ( J = f g S ; 0 l e T [ ] " 
c Y j 7 Y s 0 O I Z B > e X > m 7 C b x \ t # s / [ u z P Y [ " g 9 p Y k w l [ 
9 " z H 9 G 7 z Y i . % R ^ + ( " ? T k E C & c k B % % 5 5 W # ^ T 0 . C w / { 
4 = ] e * r B ] V 0   % a X y ( . ) A . z b s Z p $ # F z E U t b z s V p Q d t 
7 { Y p ' D # Y 6 o B 3 ; ^ u o T 8 R z G t / y + t Q , / J c p } \ i q - W t S 
B 1 J s Z R % U . , H | A ? a v p 7 H t s > r > L o : 6 ] Y 4 e H Z ] ] < 4 ( L 
G m S T ) # 1 : f ` " F @ G 4 _ q F 6 p z " U * " . / ` B J N B 0 c : d S d } F 
l 8 F " : e 4 r ) / V A | n G Y K J U [ E k [ % S 4 J \ r z ; 6 * | N s 9 { _ 8 
d d - H 0 J ` x ( { d s ( ` ) * 6 V C 2 S z B 8 8 [ ! Q ( a 1 I / P 0 u 6 9 G a 
Y _ > ^ # u l . 7 ? E \ 0 } : s + D S T U K S ' Z j Y 1 g 0 & 7 i W ) O 5 E ? & 
c | M r ` # L & + Z : 5 = - Y d B   Y ? T A x , v " l i h B " d 0 / I ^ C ' W F 
\ S   o ! 1 4 O a " y V ! 9 1 + v c b O 8 ] 7 b w % " B 7 Y 9 L 1 " Z . Z & R x
```

Comment: Why linewise? `with open(argv[1]) as f: print( f.read().count('8') )`  will do it without the loop. Reads the whole file into ram though, so dont do it with BIG files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate over a file, you are looping over each line in that file.

As you noted yourself, your solution does not account for there being more than one "8" in each line.
You want to add `a.count("8")` to the counter rather than just `1`.

This is how I would write the code you have in your else block:

```
counter = 0

with open(argv[1]) as file:
    for line in file:
       counter += line.count("8")

print(counter)
```

Using `with` just means it will handle any issues opening your file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort to help me. Again, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Omner James Crissanto No worries! Could you accept my answer if it cleared things up?

Comment: I still can't vote up because I'm just new here.

Comment: @OmnerJamesCrisanto [voting up vs accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)